# SQL-Select ends up in an Error when combined

Tags: sql, sqlbase, sqltalk

I try to do a simple select for some duplicates but my sql statement always end up with this error:

> Command not properly ended

What I have is a table like this

```
EAN              STR
=============    ====
8030524096397    AAAA
8030524096397    BBBB
8030524096731    XXXX
8030524096731    YYYY
8030524096324    CCCC
```

My select is actually simple

```
SELECT EAN, COUNT(*) FROM ean GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Reults:

```
EAN               COUNT(*)
=============     ========
8030524096397        2
8030524096731        2
```

Everything is fine until here! Now I want the `STR` of the duplicates and try this

```
SELECT * FROM EAN E 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT EAN, COUNT(*) FROM ean GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )  
R ON 
E.EAN = R.EAN;
```

But this results this error.

It exactly says this:

```
SELECT * FROM EAN E
INNER JOIN ( SELECT EAN, COUNT(*) FROM ean GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )  R ON
^
Error: Command not properly ended
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Information to DB:** Gupta Centura SQLBase 7.0.1

Comment: @Simo no, that's not the problem, i've tested it right now. Adding AS results the error to the AS position ^^

Comment: @AndrewB, sadly not. I tried all in one row. Same result :(

Comment: SQL is case sensitive right? You are using "EAN" and "ean" seemingly as table names and column names, in the first FROM part, you select from "EAN" and in the join you select from "ean". If they are different tables, for "GROUP BY ean", is ean not the table name you are selecting from rather than the column to group by?

Comment: @AndrewB: no. (standard) SQL is **not** case sensitive. `EAN`, `Ean` and `ean` are all the same identifiers.

Comment: trough testings there is no matter of CS. But good idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think SQLBase 7.01 supports proper ANSI `JOIN` syntax (aside:  what a good reason to use a more modern product).  The error indicates a problem on the `INNER JOIN`.

Here are two possible solutions.

First, yucky archaic `join` syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM EAN E,
     ( SELECT EAN, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ean GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )  
R 
WHERE E.EAN = R.EAN;
```

Second, `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM EAN E
WHERE E.EAN IN ( SELECT EAN FROM ean GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Comment: Some people seem to be not from this wold to know all this stuff :D The first one doesn't work but the second one does. This select takes a lot of time but actually results this what I want. Thank you :)

Comment: by the way, of corse I know we should use a newer db, but in this case this is sadly not possible. Actually it's a running system and to build this new it would cost to much time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM EAN E 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT EA.EAN, COUNT(*) Cnt 
    FROM ean EA
    GROUP BY EA.ean 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    ) R ON E.EAN = R.EAN;
```

I gave an alias Cnt to COUNT(*). This should make the error go away.

Comment: Try again. I gave an alias to the table ean in the sub query.

Comment: sorry, no. Jumps out on 'INNER'

Answer (score 0):

Try this (adding aliases to the tables with `AS` keyword)

```
SELECT * FROM EAN AS E 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT EAN, COUNT(*) FROM ean GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS R 
ON 
E.EAN = R.EAN;
```

Comment: using AS causes the same error but the curser jumps to the position of AS and not to innerjoin. AS can not be used in this case I guess.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: What happens if you just drop the `AS` but leave everything else the same as @AishvaryaKarthik's answer?

Comment: As i commented in my post: Gupta Centura SQLBase 7.0.1

Comment: I know this has already been answered , but if you need to know more about SQLBase, here is a link to some manuals for every version from v8 thru v12.1  :  http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/